# Is there a function to retrieve all current logged-in users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a function to retrieve all current logged-in users for Drupal 7?

I tried to build a query based on [Get all the logged-in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091201/get-all-logged-in-user-in-drupal).

```php
$query->join('users', 'u', 's.uid = u.uid'); //JOIN sessions with users
$query->fields('u',array('name')) //SELECT the fields from node
  ->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC') //ORDER BY timestamp
  ->range(0,10); //LIMIT to 10 records
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
$result = $query->execute();
```

I'm still missing something on to retrieve all names from `$result` as an array, and on how to limit the query to return the users who were active in the last 5 minutes.

I need to put these into an array with their usernames in *#title* and their user IDs in *#href*.

Comment: trying to make sense of the result sets using db_query https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174, wondering if I will need to use db_select() in order to put the results in to the array as I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve users logged in last 5 minutes :

```
$users_results = db_query('SELECT u.uid , u.name FROM users u 
                   WHERE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - u.access ) < (5*60)')
          ->fetchAllKeyed();
dsm($users_results);
```

**EDIT**

Like asked :

```
foreach($users_results as $uid => $name){
  $users[$name] = array('#title' => $name , '#href' => $uid);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks Fky, that worked. Now I just have to figure out how to put all names into individual arrays instead, with the format: Name -> #title = name. 

Might you be able to help? Can open a new question for it.
I already tried `$usernames = array(); while($user_array = db_fetch_array($users)) {$usernames[] = $user_array['#title'];}` instead of fetchAllKeyed.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand what exactly you want , what is final structure you want ? fetchAllKeyed store it like `$users[232423] => 'username'` , post your query

Comment: I have updated my question with an example array, have you seen it already?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Fky, you rock, just had to switch "$name => $uid" in foreach loop :)